# Joomla PHP how to logout a user if IP match

Tags: php, joomla

So in Joomla what is the correct plugin to modify or file path to logout a user if their IP matches a specific IP.

Here is my code it is very simple just need to know the correct place to put it.

```
$ip_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if ($ip_addr === "171.227.2.22") {
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->logout();
}
```

Comment: why not do it at root level through htaccess, assuming its an apache server. Like so. Order Deny,Allow
Deny from IP HERE

Comment: @norcaljohnny Because I want to log any user out with this IP not ban them. There must be a plugin that checks on each page they visit.

Comment: As long as you never want to load balance the site your idea will work fine.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I don't need to for a small unpopular site i just need to know what plugin file i should add my code to etc that would perform this check i have tried plugins\authentication\joomla\joomla.php public function onUserAuthenticate    But yet i am still logged in and not being logged out.